# Getting django rest framework jwt authentication to work [django rest, angular 5]

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, http-headers, django-rest-framework-jwt

so I have installed djanogo rest framework JWT and set the settings and authetication classes. According to this guide. I will leave out the settings as they are correct, and that is not where the problem lies. It is also to not post too much code

https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

I then make a call to a authorization view on my server from the front end

```
 let token = "hardcoded token just to get the service working"; 
    if(token != null){
      this.authservice.authorizetoken(token)
        .subscribe(
          (req: any)=>{
            console.log(req);
          }
        );

// grab the permissions a user has and who they are by token
    authorizetoken(token){
      return this.http.get(userauthorization, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'JWT' + token )
      });
    }
```

then in my django here is the view code:

```
class UserAuthorization(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.user)
        return Response({})
```

but I keep getting anonymousUser returned. Shouldn't it be a user object since I am passing a token in the header?

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How is your config of drf jwt? Or you can debug on function "authenticate" in class "BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication". This is a class of drf jwt and this handle return an user or not, so you can finds what exactly error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation the headers should be in format `Authorization: JWT <your_token>`. When you are setting the token in headers inside your `authorizetoken` function, you are missing a white-space between `'JWT'+ token`. This might be the problem for not authenticating the user. Have you tried the endpoint with Postman?

Comment: Last night I was reading the docs and thought that may be the problem. I just got to my computer and am going to test it out. Thank you